# How to place text right next to table

Tags: tables, positioning

I am trying to use minipage to get a table next to some text like in the image below. I read on the topic but can't seem to get it together. Any help is appreciated. I am very new to this so if someone could tell me what I am doing wrong that would be great.

I'm getting the following errors:

```
line 22: Not in outer par mode. \begin{table}[h]
line 22: Undefined control sequence \begin{table}[h]
line 22: Missing number, treated as zero \begin{table}[h]
line 3: Overfull \hbox (2.60513pt too wide) in paragraph
line 23: Overfull \hbox (117.52068pt too wide) in paragraph
line 21: Overfull \hbox (20.2359pt too wide) in paragraph
```

I know that the \hbox can be fixed by appending % to the end of some lines (maybe?) but I am not quite sure on which lines that is appropriate.

Here is the code from the two files i'm making.

test_title.tex

```
\documentclass[pdftex,12pt,letterpaper]{report}

\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}

\newcommand{\labno}{3}
\newcommand{\labtitle}{Fuerzas Hidrostaticas}
\newcommand{\authorname}{Author 1 \\ Author 2 \\ Author 3 \\ Author 4}
\newcommand{\instructor}{Instructor}
\newcommand{\classno}{Laboratorio INGE4010}

\begin{document}
\input{./title.tex}
\end{document}
```

title.tex

```
\begin{titlepage}

\noindent
\includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth]{UPRMlogo}%
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.7\textwidth}
\centering
Universidad de Puerto Rico \\
Recinto de Mayaguez\\
Departamento de Ingenieria Mecanica
\end{minipage} %
\includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth]{UPRMlogo}

\vspace*{\stretch{7}}
\begin{center}
\textsc{Laboratorio \#\labno \ \labtitle}
\end{center}
\vspace{\stretch{6}}

\vfill

\begin{minipage}{.2\textwidth} %
\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabular}{|l|r|}
\hline
\textbf{Partes del Informe} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Calificación}} \\ \hline
Introducción                & /10                                        \\ \hline
Datos y Cálculos            & /20                                        \\ \hline
Análisis de Resultados      & /45                                        \\ \hline
Conclusiones                & /20                                        \\ \hline
Referencia y Apéndice       & /5                                         \\ \hline
Total                       & /100                                       \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{minipage} %
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth} %
\begin{flushright}
\textsc{\authorname \\ \classno \\ \instructor \\ \today}
\end{flushright}
\end{minipage} %
\end{titlepage}
```

[image: Example]

Comment: There may be other problems, but: You can't put a floating environment (`table`) inside a `minipage` environment.

Comment: In other words: comment out the lines: `\begin{table}[h]` and `\end{table}`.  Also probably want to add a `\noindent` before your first `\begin{minipage}` and give the second one something less than a full `\textwidth` -- maybe `0.8\textwidth` instead....

Comment: A `tabular` environment need not be in a `table` environment.

Comment: So I deleted like jon suggested and that worked. I implemented the solution of egreg since it also took care of my issue with accents in spanish words and changed the language of \today.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no need for a `tabular` environment to be inside a `table`.

Here's a simplified version of your title page:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\newcommand{\labno}{3}
\newcommand{\labtitle}{Fuerzas Hidrostaticas}
\newcommand{\authorname}{Author 1 \\ Author 2 \\ Author 3 \\ Author 4}
\newcommand{\instructor}{Instructor}
\newcommand{\classno}{Laboratorio INGE4010}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
\centering

\includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth]{UPRMlogo}%
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.7\textwidth}
\centering
Universidad de Puerto Rico \\
Recinto de Mayaguez\\
Departamento de Ingenieria Mecanica
\end{minipage}%
\includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth]{UPRMlogo}

\vspace*{\stretch{7}}

\textsc{Laboratorio \#\labno \ \labtitle}

\vspace{\stretch{6}}

\vfill

\begin{tabular}{@{}|l|r|@{}}
\hline
\textbf{Partes del Informe} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Calificación}} \\ \hline
Introducción                & /10                                        \\ \hline
Datos y Cálculos            & /20                                        \\ \hline
Análisis de Resultados      & /45                                        \\ \hline
Conclusiones                & /20                                        \\ \hline
Referencia y Apéndice       & /5                                         \\ \hline
Total                       & /100                                       \\ \hline
\end{tabular}%
\hfill
{\scshape
\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
\authorname \\ \classno \\ \instructor \\ \today
\end{tabular}}

\end{titlepage}

\end{document}
```

Note that you shouldn't pass the `pdftex` option to the class or to the `graphicx` package. I used `demo` because I don't have the logos, remove it.

[image]

Comment: \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\begin{tabular}{@{}|l|r|@{}}
{\scshape

I'm wondering what these do. I see that Bernard's suggestion also adds the accents to spanish words but doesn't change the language of \today. I am assuming that the accents are available because of \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} ? Thank you for your help.

Comment: The accents are available mainly because of the `T1` encoding of the font. Btw, you should use `Latin Modern`(package `lmodern`), which is T1 encoded, and not the default  `Computer Modern` if you use a language with accented letters, or you'll have problems with hyphenation.

Comment: What changed the language of the date to spanish?

Comment: The "Spanish" option in the Babel package.

Answer (score 3):

I propose to use `booktabs` and `cellspace` to improve the look and spacing of your tabular. Don't puut it in a table environment since it doesn't float.

```
\documentclass[pdftex,12pt,letterpaper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{3pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{3pt}

\newcommand{\labno}{3}
\newcommand{\labtitle}{Fuerzas Hidrostaticas}
\newcommand{\authorname}{Author 1 \\ Author 2 \\ Author 3 \\ Author 4}
\newcommand{\instructor}{Instructor}
\newcommand{\classno}{Laboratorio INGE4010}

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}

  \noindent
  \includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth]{uprm_logo.jpg}%
  \begin{minipage}[b]{0.7\textwidth}
    \centering
    Universidad de Puerto Rico \\
    Recinto de Mayaguez\\
    Departamento de Ingenieria Mecanica
  \end{minipage} %
  \includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth]{logo_upr.png}

  \vspace*{\stretch{7}}
  \begin{center}
    \textsc{Laboratorio \#\labno \ \labtitle}
  \end{center}
  \vspace{\stretch{6}}

  \vfill

  \noindent
  \begin{minipage}{.2\textwidth}%
    \begin{tabular}{@{}Slr@{}}
      \toprule
      \textbf{Partes del Informe} & \textbf{Calificación} \\
      \midrule
      Introducción & /10 \\
      Datos y Cálculos & /20 \\
      Análisis de Resultados & /45 \\
      Conclusiones & /20 \\
      Referencia y Apéndice & /5 \\
      Total & /100 \\
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
  \end{minipage} %
  \hfill
  \begin{minipage}{0.7\textwidth} %
    \begin{flushright}
      \textsc{\authorname \\[1ex] \classno \\[1ex] \instructor \\[1ex] \today}
    \end{flushright}
  \end{minipage}
  %
\end{titlepage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That worked great, I am wondering what these do: \setlength\cellspacetoplimit{3pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{3pt}

I initially thought they would make the space between the margins less but when I run it in Tex the margins look exactly the same as all other suggestions and my own. Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: No: they ensure a minimal vertical spacing between a row and the above and below rows. You surely already noticed tables in LaTeX generally have a very tight vertical spacing.